# Calling function with random output twice

Tags: functions, random

I would like to call a function, which creates some random output (let's say a random integer) in a single expression twice. A minimal example:

```
Test := RandomInteger[2]
SumTest = Test + Test
```

Here, the both values "Test" in the second line are different. I want them to be the same, i.e. the output of the second line should be 0, 2 or 4 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy peasy.

```
With[{t = Test}, t + t]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!